# Role exception for a settings sub menu

Tags: php, user-roles, sub-menu

Im fairly new to PHP so bare with me. So i have a sub menu in the backoffice settings and i need to grant an exception for this sub menu for specific users, but i have no ideia how to do that. This is the sub menu:

```js
private function setup() {

        fm_register_submenu_page( 'app-items', 'options-page', 'Definições das Apps', 'Definições das Apps', 'edit_theme_options' );
        add_action( 'fm_submenu_app-items', array( $this, 'submenu_apps_init' ) );

    }


public function submenu_apps_init() {

            $news_push = new Fieldmanager_TextField( 'Prefixo do push das notícias', array(
            'input_type'  => 'text',
            'description' => 'O prefixo escolhido será utilizado no push das notícias para a app',
            'attributes'  => array(
                'maxlength' => 40,
            )
        ));

        $fm = new Fieldmanager_Group( array(
            'name'     => 'app-items',
            'children' => array(
                'news_push'     => $news_push,
            )
        ) );
        $fm->activate_submenu_page();
    }
```

I need to add an exception for a specific role i have, that by default doesn't have the privileges to access this submenus.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) a list of roles and capabilities, if you want to check if the user has a certain role, you can:

```
$the_user = wp_get_current_user();//we get the current user
if ( in_array( 'the_name_of_your_role', (array) $the_user->roles ) ) {
    //the user has the rol, add the submenu here
}
```

you can use [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) if you want to check if the user has a specific capability, like this:

```
if( current_user_can( 'publish_pages' ) ){
    //the user has the capability do something here
}
```